# extract data from xml files using batch

Tags: xml, batch-file

I'am looking for a batch script which looks trough hundreds of XML files and extracts certain values I need.
The output file can be txt.

The XML files look all like this example:

```
<Info typeKey="000202" shortNUM="0S52042"/>

<testInfo physicalname="DATADATATATA" testTime="2017-04"  testDura="0" >
```

Iam only interested in: **shortNUM, testTime and testDura**

Thanks for reading and help in advance!

Comment: Download [msxsl.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714), a tiny tool that runs [tag:XSLT] on the Windows command line. XSLT can transform XML to text, and the batch file can use a `for` loop to go over your files.

Comment: Mhm i need a .bat file which is linked later to access ? excel as a macro :(

Comment: You seem to be confused about what technology you want to use. If you have Office+Visual Basic then you certainly don't need batch files.

Comment: my task is to find a script for .bat which fullfiles the purpose to look for those values in those xml files. have no other choice by doing so.

Comment: @Tomalak: I am confused by your comment. As far as I know, XML files _are_ text files! I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, ultimately you are wrong. XML files represent hierarchically structured data that by chance happens to be stored in text form, with very following a very strict set of rules. If you treat it as plain text, you ignore the special semantics of XML, like file encoding, escape sequences, whitespace handling rules, CTADA sections, or namespaces. All the things that make XML work are lost when you treat XML as text. And *that* means your program will be unstable and produce incorrect output even for correct input.

Comment: The batch file above makes my brain hurt and it does not need to be fixed, but **replaced**.

Comment: Please read this help topic: [mcve]

Comment: It doesn't need to be fixed. still no solution and thanks for advice.

Comment: @Tomalak: Did you misread my comment, perhaps? I never asked you what XML files "represents" and I said nothing about how I want to "treat" XML in any way! (And what a hell is _"my program"_???) I really don't understand your convoluted reply to a simple question, but if you are trying to suggest that XML files are _not_ text files, then ultimately you are wrong: all files comprised of printable ASCII characters with "lines" delimited by CR+LF control characters _are_ **text files**!

Comment: My reply is not "convoluted" just because you did not understand it. XML is not text. Treat it as text at your own peril.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat)

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('xpath "c:\my.xml" "//@testTime"') do set "testtime=%%#"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('xpath "c:\my.xml" "//@shortNUM"') do set "shortNUM=%%#"

echo %testtime% -- %shortNUM%
```

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know that.

Comment: Mhm I have little to no experience in .bat , xpath.bat won't work when I do it :(

Comment: @Mingz - try just with `xpath "c:\my.xml" "//@shortNUM"` in the command prompt and see if there are any errors. Are you sure that your xml is well formatted?

Comment: The XML should be fine. I used a .bat script before. The problem with my older script is that I have to type in manually which values Iam looking for. To make the macro work in excel or access I need a batch scipt which is automatically looking for these values mentioned above. I'll post my older script in my question